# Try different credentials PS script SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh, credentials

I have this script and cannot work correctly .. I try to connect with 2 users ; if one doesn't work try other one.

#1. Try user and pass1 if is not good try #2. user and pass2.

*problem is with winscp users ; I really don't know how to implement 2 try connection

```
    if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))  
{  
  $arguments = "& '" +$myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
 
$db = import-csv -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\db.csv"
 
$inputID = Read-Host -Prompt "ID"
 
$entry = $db | where-Object {$_.HostName  -eq  $inputID}

if ($inputID -eq $entry.HostName){

    "$inputID Ok!"
}
else{

    "$inputID nu exista in baza de date!"

    $title    = 'Title'
    $question = 'Doriti sa introduceti un ID nou in Baza de Date?'
    $choices  = '&Yes', '&No'

$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
    if ($decision -eq 0) {
    Write-Host 'confirmed'

    $ID = Read-Host -Prompt "Introduceti ID"
    $IP = Read-Host -Prompt "Introduceti IP"

$wrapper = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ HostName = $ID; IP = $IP }
Export-Csv -Append -InputObject $wrapper -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\db.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force 
$dbTrimmer = Get-Content -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\db.csv"
$dbTrimmer.Replace('","',",").TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') | Out-File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\db.csv" -Force -Confirm:$false
    Exit
    }
    else{
    Write-Host 'No'
    Exit
    }
}

Write-Host "IP:" $entry.IP

    $User = "user"
    $Password = "pass"
    $Command = "C:\Info.exe"

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $entry.IP -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $entry.IP
    UserName = "$User"
    Password = "$Password"
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = "true"
}
 
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

$file = "Dev.log", "Info.dat"
$localPath = "E:\Arhive\*" 
$remotePath = "/C:/Program Files/Dev.log", "/C:/Program File/Info.dat"

try {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Check exists files
    foreach ($remotePath in $remotePath)
{
    if ($session.FileExists($remotePath))
    {
        Write-Host "Fisierul $remotePath exista"
        
        # Transfer files

        $session.GetFiles($remotePath, $localPath).Check()
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Fisierul $remotePath NU exista"
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $session.Dispose()
}

foreach ($file in "E:\loguri\Dev.log", "E:\loguri\Info.dat") {
    if (Test-Path $file) {
    Compress-Archive $file -DestinationPath "E:\Arhive\$inputID.zip" -Update
    Remove-Item $file
    }
}

# Stergere fisiere din Arhive mai vechi de 60 minute

$Files = get-childitem 'E:\Arhive' | Where-Object PSIsContainer -eq $false
$LimitTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60)
$Files | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.CreationTime -lt $LimitTime -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $LimitTime) {
    Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force
    Write-Host "Am sters $Files pentru ca sunt mai vechi de $LimitTime !"
     }
}
```

Here is all my script. In this moment all works very well , just I want to add 2 users for auth. If 1 fail try other one.
Any ideea ? Thank you

Comment: Hello Martin Invoke-SSHCommand - execute an exe via ssh = $command

Comment: So sorry, I'm newbie :) I post all my script. Works fine but I want to add 2 different credentials , if 1 fail try other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't test this myself, but I think I would go about it like below:

```
$User         = "SameUser"
$Password     = "Pass1"
$sPassword    = "Pass2"
$Command      = "C:\Info.exe"
$secpasswd    = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$ssecpasswd   = ConvertTo-SecureString $sPassword -AsPlainText -Force

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

try {
    # try the first credentials
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)
    $SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $entry.IP -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
} 
catch {
    # first one failed, try second credentials
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $ssecpasswd)
    $SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $entry.IP -Credential $sCredentials -AcceptKey:$true -Verbose
}
try {
    Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId $SessionID.SessionId -Command $Command -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    throw   
}

# create a hashtable with the first password
$options = @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $entry.IP
    UserName = $User
    Password = $Password
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = $true
}

try {
    # Set up session options using first password
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property $options
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    # Try Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
} 
catch {
    # Set up session options using second password
    $options['Password'] = $sPassword
    try {
        $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property $options
        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
        # Try Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Could not open WinSCP session: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        throw
    }
}

try {
    # Check if exists files. 
    # Make sure variables $remotePath and $localPath are defined on top of the script
    foreach ($remoteFile in $remotePath) {
        if ($session.FileExists($remoteFile)) {
            $session.GetFiles($remotePath, $localPath).Check()
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "File '$remoteFile' not found"
        }
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Could not open WinSCP session: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
finally {
    if ($session) { $session.Dispose() }
}
```

Comment: Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exit
status 0.
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "user".
Access denied.
Authentication failed."
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\PS_test.ps1:139 char:5
+     $session.Open($sessionOptions)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SessionRemoteException

This is line 139 : $session.Open($sessionOptions)

Comment: @Bogdan I have added a nested try{..}catch{..} now. BTW, it seems [GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#sshhostkeypolicy) is obsoleted and you should use `GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAny`. Again.. cannot test myself unfortunately

Comment: It's authentication problem, it has nothing to do with the "hostkey". (Though obviously one should not use any "give up security" options, but that's a different topic). – Which is line `139 `? Can you edit a complete error output you get into your question? – It would also be nice, if you answer my question in the comment above.

Comment: Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Session is already opened"
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.ps1:112 char:5
+     $session.Open($sessionOptions)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

Comment: 139 line : $session.Open($sessionOptions)

Comment: Do you create a new `Session` before the second `Open`? `$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session`.  Like the Theo's answer does? + We know that 139 is `$session.Open($sessionOptions)`, but WHICH ONE?

Comment: I post my full script (1st post)

Comment: Where does the script in your question attempt to do, what Theo suggested in his answer? + We do not want your full script, we want [mcve]. + I cannot imagine how can your script with its single call to `$session.Open` and no loops can ever produce the *"Session is already opened"* exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238597/discussion-between-bogdan-and-martin-prikryl).